# Primefaces extensions ajaxErrorHandler not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, wildfly-8, primefaces-extensions

On WildFly 8-1 I have `primefaces-5.1.jar` and `primefaces-extensions-2.1.0.jar` in my webapps `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

I have configured `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">
  <application>
    <el-resolver>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver</el-resolver>
  </application>

  <factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
  </factory>
</faces-config>
```

I have the following JSF.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form id="form">
    <pe:ajaxErrorHandler body="ERROR"/>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{dossierResumen.excepcion}" value="Excepción"/>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

where `DossierResumen#excepcion()` is

```
public void excepcion() {
  throw new NullPointerException("EXCEPCION! EXCEPCION!");
}
```

When I click the button, I get no popups at all; the page gets redirected to the URL for error 500 defined in `web.xml`. In the logs, I get the following wall of stacktrace:

What am I doing wrong?

> 15:44:14,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: EXCEPCION! EXCEPCION! 15:44:14,206
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)  at
>   es.imasmallorca.selene.webone.jsf.controller.dossier.DossierResumen.excepcion(DossierResumen.java:55)
>   15:44:14,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   es.imasmallorca.selene.webone.jsf.controller.dossier.DossierResumen$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.excepcion(Unknown
>   Source) 15:44:14,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   15:44:14,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   15:44:14,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   15:44:14,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 15:44:14,207 ERROR
>   [stderr] (default task-42)    at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275) 15:44:14,207
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>   15:44:14,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>   15:44:14,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>   15:44:14,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>   15:44:14,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>   15:44:14,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>   15:44:14,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>   15:44:14,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
>   15:44:14,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>   15:44:14,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>   15:44:14,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>   15:44:14,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>   15:44:14,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) 15:44:14,209
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>   15:44:14,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
>   15:44:14,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>   15:44:14,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
>   15:44:14,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   15:44:14,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>   15:44:14,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   15:44:14,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
>   15:44:14,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
>   15:44:14,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   15:44:14,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
>   15:44:14,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
>   15:44:14,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>   15:44:14,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>   15:44:14,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   15:44:14,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   15:44:14,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>   15:44:14,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   15:44:14,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   15:44:14,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
>   15:44:14,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
>   15:44:14,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
>   15:44:14,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
>   15:44:14,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
>   15:44:14,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
>   15:44:14,214 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   15:44:14,214 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   15:44:14,214 ERROR [stderr] (default task-42)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 15:44:14,214 SEVERE
>   [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler]
>   (default task-42) EXCEPCION! EXCEPCION!:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: EXCEPCION! EXCEPCION!     at
>   es.imasmallorca.selene.webone.jsf.controller.dossier.DossierResumen.excepcion(DossierResumen.java:55)
>   [classes:]    at
>   es.imasmallorca.selene.webone.jsf.controller.dossier.DossierResumen$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.excepcion(Unknown
>   Source) [classes:]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
>   [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]     at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>   [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>   [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>   [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>   [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>   [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]  at
>   javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>   [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>   [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]  at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]

Update:

At Guaido79's request, my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>seleneWar</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/500.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jsf/ProjectStage</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
  </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I don't see any exception type on web.xml.
Try putting

    <exception-type>java.lang.NullPointerException</exception-type>
(or other exception or throwable for all exception) in your error page. If I remember primefaces read error page from there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two modes in that component: simple and extended mode.

In the simple mode, you don't need to specify anything in your `faces-config.xml`. So you can delete these lines:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>

<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

Or delete the whole `faces-config.xml` file since it's the only thing you have in there. Then you can test simple mode, which is working fine without defining anything else in your web.xml. ***This might be enough for your needs***.

From the error trace, it seems that in extended mode (with that `faces-config.xml` configuration), the component needs to have an error page defined in your `web.xml`. You don't want a redirection to an error page, so if you add the following code to your `web.xml` for example works, but not for your needs:

```
<error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
   <location>/error/500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Anyway, it's HIGHLY recommended to use the [`p:ajaxExceptionHandler`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml) native component since it looks like the authors of PrimeFaces Extensions <s>will probably remove the component in the future since it's no longer necessary [(link)](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=35955)</s> already removed the component in version 3.2.0. [(link)](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/327)

Comment: More to the point, and the info about "pe:ajaxErrorHandler" becoming deprecated is a nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

How it's configured your web.xml? 
For me it's working with this configuration:

example web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/pages/errorpages/sessione-scaduta.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/pages/errorpages/runtime-error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<application>
        <message-bundle>ValidationMessages</message-bundle>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>/Bundle</base-name>
            <var>bundle</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <el-resolver>
            org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver
        </el-resolver>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>it</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <view-handler>it.infogroup.wrl.web.utils.PathTrimViewHandler</view-handler>
    </application>

    <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>
            org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
        </exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>
```

With this configuration you will be redirected on error.

If you need popup you need to change the code like this (from primefaces showcase):

```
<p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="java.lang.NullPointerException"
                            update="exceptionDialog"
                            onexception="PF('exceptionDialog').show();" />

    <p:dialog id="exceptionDialog" header="Exception '#{pfExceptionHandler.type}' occured!" widgetVar="exceptionDialog"
              height="500px">
        Message: #{pfExceptionHandler.message} <br/>
        StackTrace: <h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.formattedStackTrace}" escape="false" /> <br />

        <p:button onclick="document.location.href = document.location.href;"
                  value="Reload!"
                  rendered="#{pfExceptionHandler.type == 'javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException'}" />
    </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Now I feel silly, I focused in the Primefaces Extensions component and did not know a similar one existed in vanilla Primefaces... +1 at the moment; if nobody comes forward with a solution for the Primefaces Extensions component (it looks like better) I will award the bounty to you.

Comment: Added the web.xml to my question.